# Ubuntu 15.10 having troubles with internet connection (first time boot)

Tags: networking, 15.10, internet

This is my first time that I've installed Ubuntu on this machine and I'm running the 15.10 version (most recent one).

I installed Ubuntu and all seemed fine. I went ahead and connected to my home network via wireless and it showed me a valid connection but when I go to open up Firefox, it does not seem to work at all. It says that the server cannot be found.

I have restarted several times, checked my internet connection and even restarted the router, yet nothing works. I have also tried pinging www.google.com but I get 'unknown host www.google.com'.

I have looked at a lot of threads about this and none of them seem to work for me.

Why can I not connect to the internet?

EDIT:

I have figured out the problem myself.

I went into

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

and below everything else I added:

```
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

To use Google's DNS servers. This seemed to fix my problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I've edited the post with the output.

Comment: Please also add `ifconfig` , `iwconfig` and `route -n` outputs.

Comment: I am using another laptop to type this right now. Which bit of the out do you need? I cannot copy and paste it, so I have to copy it all out.

Comment: You can copy and paste the text, then save it to a flash drive, etc.

Comment: Ok, I've included those as well. Anymore?

Comment: It looks OK. You nay have some trouble with ISP or your router.

Comment: Why did you remove the outputs? In this condition the question will be closed as unclear or too broad.

Comment: I removed them because you said they were fine anyway, and because they contain some information which I think isn't supposed to be public to anyone online. If it's a necessity, I will re-add  them back.

Comment: Please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result.

Comment: @TeeKayM: You can mask or abridge the private information in log files (e. g. MAC and personal IP addresses and network names) if you want.

Comment: I have figured out the problem and I've replied with it below. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the problem myself.

I went into

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

and below everything else I added:

```
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

To use Google's DNS servers. This seemed to fix my problem.